# Why is a different outcome occurring on the following use of sort

Tags: python, sorting

I was doing a puzzle and where i had to add 2 lists having same length to a new list and sort the list by the second element of the list.

```
for x in range(n):
            tmp.append([start[x],end[x]])
```

where start and end are lists containing equal elements and n is the length of start and end.

Now, idk why a difference / error occurs between the use of following code.

```
end.sort()
for x in range(n):
    tmp.append([start[x],end[x]])
```

and

```
for x in range(n):
    tmp.append([start[x],end[x]])
tmp.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
```

EDIT:-
Input list

```
start=[1, 3, 0, 5, 8, 5]
end=[2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9]
```

output by sorting first

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 6], [5, 7], [8, 9], [5, 9]]
```

output by sorting later

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 6], [5, 7], [8, 9], [5, 9]]
```

works fine for this list but doesn't work for a bigger array
(array contains 80 elements thats why not uploading here)

Comment: Show us your input and output values!

Comment: Added the input output for a small array, don't know how to upload a text file.(it contains the 80 elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort `end` first, you combine the original order of start with the sorted order of end.

If you combine the two lists first and then sort by the end element, the start elements will get reordered, too, as they "tag along" with their end partner. Consider

```
start = [1, 2, 3]
end   = [3, 2, 1]
```

Now, sorting `end` and combining, you'll end up with:

```
start = [1, 2, 3]
end   = [1, 2, 3]
# =>
tmp = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Combining first, however, produces:

```
tmp = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1]]
```

And sorting this by the second element, will shuffle the old start elements as well:

```
tmp.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
# [[3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Side note: Check out `zip`:

```
tmp = list(zip(start, end))
```

Comment: Hey, Im realtively new so just asking to confirm, zip and using for loop takes same time But Zip is a more elegant form of writing ,right?

Comment: Yeah, `zip` is the way to go. It is made exactly for this case.